# Cant read api link in android, kotlin, async

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous

I try to read info form my API: http://localhost:5001/Subject => In android: http://10.0.2.2:5001/Subject. And my app has crash. (App work with another link APIrestfull in Internet)

```
inner class API : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>(){
    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String {
        var content = StringBuilder();
        val url = URL(p0[0]);
        var urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection;
        val inputStreamReader = InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        var line = "";

        try {
            do{
                line=bufferedReader.readLine();
                if (line!=null) content.append(line);
            } while (line!= null);
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (e : Exception) {
            Log.d("AAA",e.toString());
        }
        return content.toString();
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "${result.toString()}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

My api is asp.net core webapi.

Error: [My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAoOH.png)

Comment: Please post errors as text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to fix it: (Thanks all)

```
if (conn instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
    HttpsURLConnection httpsConn = (HttpsURLConnection) conn;
    httpsConn.setSSLSocketFactory(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getInsecure(0, null));
    httpsConn.setHostnameVerifier(new AllowAllHostnameVerifier());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your exception
`Caused by java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 10.0.2.2 not permitted`
you are trying to access your endpoint over HTTP, which is disabled for security reasons by default on android.

See this answer on a similar post for how to [disable this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/8934933), which is okay for **development purposes**.

**But please**, if you want to release your program in any way, don't change this setting and make your API available over HTTPS as well.